# How to stay Colour change even I move to another position in android

Tags: android, selected, mode

I am doing an application where there are 5 questions and 5 Answers(in the form of button) for each question .I want to place the selected value(Selected Answers) from each question  into an variable in the form of array.While we select any option  the button color will change into another color and we proceed into next question here also I'm selecting anyone of the option.After that we are going Back to first question the option should remain in the selected mode itself with color change.My problem is that when I'm selected option the color changes and i'm going to next page and come back to first page the button will be in default color(That is it is not in selected mode).I'm beginner to the android and java .please help me with example?

Comment: i want to store in a variable.how?

Comment: use search engine, dont duplicate problems..

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not saving user checked answers. So screen is restoring to the default state. Try use one of the solution by: sharedPreferences or android Application or external disk or just using database. Use search in stack.

And when user will go back, data will be loaded from stored data solving your problem.